# Tensorflow error: Unsupported return value from function passed to Dataset.map()

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using `tf.data.Dataset` for `input_fn` in a TensorFlow code. I need to read all channels separately as they are stored in different files. The code below show the loading and processing function.

```
def load_images_as_tensor(image_paths, dtype=np.uint8):
    n_channels = 6
    image_paths = image_paths
    data = np.ndarray(shape=(512, 512, n_channels), dtype=dtype)
    for ix, img_path in enumerate(image_paths):
        data[:, :, ix] = load_image(img_path)
    return(data)

def process(img, pixel_stats=GLOBAL_PIXEL_STATS, use_bfloat16 = True):
    if pixel_stats is not None:
        mean, std = pixel_stats
        img = (tf.cast(img, tf.float32) - mean) / std
    if use_bfloat16:
        img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, dtype=tf.bfloat16)

    img = img.set_shape([512, 512, 6])
    return(img)

def input_fn(params):
  data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tmp2)
  data = data.map(lambda x: tf.py_func(load_images_as_tensor,[x], tf.uint8))
  data = data.map(lambda x: process(x, GLOBAL_PIXEL_STATS, True))
  return(data)
```

Due to the use of `tf.py_func`, TensorFlow is not able to get the shape of the input. After going through a TensorFlow issue on github, I thought that specifying the shape manually would fix the error. I'm still getting error

> TypeError: Unsupported return value from function passed to
>   Dataset.map(): None.

Comment: I get the same error, when I preprocess images using python functions wrapped with tf.py_func, then try to resize the images to the input size of the CNN, tensorflow is unable to get the shape of the image. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, abandoned the problem. Used TFRecords for better processing.